# I want count of saved search in idx api

Tags: saved-searches, idx

I want a count of saved search from https://www.idxhome.com/login/clientid?username=email

as an api result to post it to my website.

Comment: Without more details, I don't think I can help you. Do you have an example response from this API? It's this a RETS API or a REST API? What library/language/etc are you using?

Comment: Can you provide the IDX you are using? IDX Broker, iHomefiner, etc...? (I don't think this is a RETS feed) Also clarify if you want a count of the number of saved searches created or a count of the properties in a saved search?